# Using Now() for Foreign Countries

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to convert different date formats into an appropriate SQL DateTime format and am getting errors.

I have a client's machine that is setup with the following date format, "dd-mm-yyyy" (Localization is India)

When using Now() within VB.Net it parses the month and days backwards. I've tried the following code but get conversion errors.

```
    Dim Month As String = Nothing
    Dim Year As String = Nothing
    Dim Day As String = Nothing
    Dim Hour As String = Nothing
    Dim Minute As String = Nothing
    Dim Second As String = Nothing
    Dim strDate As String = Nothing
    Dim Date_to_SQL_DateTime As Date


    Month = DatePart(DateInterval.Month, Now()).ToString
    Year = DatePart(DateInterval.Year, Now())
    Day = DatePart(DateInterval.Day, Now())
    Hour = DatePart(DateInterval.Hour, Now())
    Minute = DatePart(DateInterval.Minute, Now())
    Second = DatePart(DateInterval.Second, Now())

    strDate = Month & “/” & Day & “/” & Year & “ “ & Hour & “:” & Minute & “:” & Second

    Date_to_SQL_DateTime = Date.ParseExact(strDate, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

strDate returns

```
1/24/2017 23:17
```

Error I'm receiving is

```
String was not recognized as a valid Datetime
```

Comment: Could you use GetDate() instead or just pass the date in as a Date parameter?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer Well that really opens up another can of worms.. and gets into using UTC time with user specific offsets. I'd rather just store the time in the DB as datetime and specific to their current time. It's a good thought and something I need to definitely do..

Comment: Can you show your insert statement?

Comment: If the format is the only problem, you could parse the date to a formated string like this 
`Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Now
  Dim format As String = "MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy"
  Console.WriteLine(time.ToString(format))` with the formats like : 

MMM     Three-letter month.
ddd     Three-letter day of the week.
d       Day of the month.
HH      Two-digit hours on 24-hour scale.
mm      Two-digit minutes.
yyyy    Four-digit year.

Comment: Why bother? instead of composing a string representation of Now() and converting that string representation back to a DateTime, simply use `Date_to_SQL_DateTime = DateTime.Now`.

Comment: You're getting an error because your format in `ParseExact` is expecting a two digit Month whereas you are passing a single digit for the month of January.  But that code makes absolutely no sense.  `DateTime` _has no format_!  You are taking `Now()` which returns a `DateTime` creating a string from its parts and then trying to turn the string back to a `DateTime`.  Why do that?  Just use `Now()`!

Comment: The problem with using Now() and passing that into a paramater for SQL is that the format from the local machine is returned as dd-mm-yyyy. That is the whole problem and it will not convert to SQL Datetime

Comment: In the interim, I just passed the Date_to_SQL_DateTime as string, and passed it into dynamic SQL to convert to SQL Datetime instead of using VB to do it, and it works fine. Now to focus on storing datetimes correctly in the DB.

Comment: _There is no format!!_  `DateTimes` in Sql server _have no format_.  They are stored as two 4 byte integers.  The only time format should be considered is when you are taking the date as input from the user and displaying the date.  If you use `DateTime` variables, then the `ToString` method will return the date in the user's local representation.

Comment: If you pass a `DateTime` variable as a parameter into Sql and the column's datatype is also `DateTime` then you avoid all this pain over formats.

Answer (score 0):

Try below. Need to make sure parameters are of same format as specified in the `ParseExact` function.

```
Dim Month As String = Nothing
Dim Year As String = Nothing
Dim Day As String = Nothing
Dim Hour As String = Nothing
Dim Minute As String = Nothing
Dim Second As String = Nothing
Dim strDate As String = Nothing
Dim Date_to_SQL_DateTime As Date

Month = DatePart(DateInterval.Month, Now()).ToString("00")
Year = DatePart(DateInterval.Year, Now()).ToString("0000")
Day = DatePart(DateInterval.Day, Now()).ToString("00")
Hour = DatePart(DateInterval.Hour, Now()).ToString("00")
Minute = DatePart(DateInterval.Minute, Now()).ToString("00")
Second = DatePart(DateInterval.Second, Now()).ToString("00")

strDate = Month & "/" & Day & "/" & Year & " " & Hour & ":" & Minute & ":" & Second
Date_to_SQL_DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```